# How to customize the meaning of the "-l" flag for GCC?

Tags: gcc, pkg-config

I have problems with GCC and I would like to use the `-l` flags in a customized way.

I would like to specify the search path for the correspondant libfoo specified by `-lfoo` , I also would like to override any internal search path in GCC, i don't want GCC to use any random lib that can solve the symbols, I only want GCC to compile with a really specific lib when `-l` is specified.

I know that there are utils such as `pkg-config` but my problem is more gcc-centric because i'm focusing on having more control on the compilation steps.

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented syntax for specifying an absolute lib path to gcc:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -l:/usr/lib/libfoo.so  #(note the colon)
```

See here: https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20130119.001059.fad11362.de.html

A more standard way to do this would simply be:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c /usr/lib/libfoo.so
```

Really, the only reason to use the `-l:` syntax is if you have a conflicting library of the same name in your search path and you can't change the search path.